# Adding xamarin android controls to visual studio toolbox

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, designer

I was working with Xamarin Visual studio and suddenly I just deleted some of the controls from Visual Studio toolbox pane in android designer.

I tried adding them using (right click on toolbox/choose items), but I don't know where the assembly of the controls live.

Does anyone know how to add the controls back?

Comment: you didn't say what version of studio and xamarin. For older versions, eg VS2005 it seems like one should reinstall studio. That might work for you and might not be too troublesome? (I've never gotten a bounty so was browsing for fun :))

Comment: You Should restore your VS settings to default, you can do it by clicking tools in menu then Import and Export Settings.

On the Import and Export Settings Wizard page, click Reset all settings and click Next.

If you want to save your current settings, click Yes, save my current settings, specify a file name,click Next.

OR

If you want to delete your current settings, choose No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings, and click Next. This option does not delete default settings, which will still be available the next time you use the wizard..

Click Finish.
I hope it helps you

Answer (score 9):

**simple fix**

> Deleting the *.tbd in the following dir on Windows worked for me...

```
C:\Users[Current user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\version of
visual studio\
```

sometimes the file was hidden so do this.

go to this folder

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application
Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\version of visual studio"
```

that's it. Happy Coding

Answer (score 3):

Yo need to have Android SDK tools and Android SDK platform tools both installed. In my case Android SDK platform tools was not installed for some reason. Got Visual studio-->Tools-->Android-->SDK Maanger and check if both the tools are isnatlled. If not please install both the packages.

Answer (score 2):

Also you have to have the latest Android SDK installed.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me deleting *.tbd didn't work.
I installed the latest Android SDK + Reinstalled Xamarin for windows did the trick.